# bash script that has sudo PW already in it so it doesn't prompt user

Tags: sudo

using Linux OS.

I want to write a bash script that needs to have sudo access - but is being run by people without this access and PW.
meaning I would have the script be execute privileges only, and would have the sudo username and PW already in it.

so that non-admin users would ./run_my_script.bash  and this script would do actions as sudo w/o prompting the user for PW.

--
yes i know i need to have this script be execute only, so they can't just read the file and then have the sudo PW.

Comment: Could you more explicitly formulate an actual question please?

Comment: Sounds like you are about to discover [`setuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). However, setuid is usually disabled for shell scripts for security reasons. Rewrite in another language (say, Python or Perl) or create a simple C wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Short version: No.

Longer version: sudo uses the *users* own password, so you cannot put it in the script.

A better approach is to configure sudo so that people can run the script. For example, if the script is `/usr/local/bin/root_stuff.sh` then put something like

```
Cmnd_Alias ROOTCMD = /usr/local/bin/root_stuff.sh
%users ALL=ROOTCMD, NOPASSWD: ROOTCMD
```

Your users can then run `sudo root_stuff.sh`

Or if that is really beyond them, put the code in `/usr/local/bin/root_stuff_inner.sh` (changing `ROOTCMD` above) and put this in `root_stuff.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/local/bin/root_stuff.sh
```